# Ruby: just-in-time gem installation?

Tags: ruby

Would it be possible to override the default "require" by adding automatic download-and-install code for any missing includes (provided that the missing include is published as a ruby gem).

Which would not work in situations where Ruby is not interfaced with a shell. But still I think it would be an interesting idea.

Is there such a mechanism in existence today?

Edit:
Removed portion about password check. I just checked and gem install doesn't seem to require me to type my password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to hijack `require` method so as gems are installed when an attempt is made to `require` them, but still you won't have access to newly installed gem in current process, because gem index has to be reloaded.

I understand the intentions but I think exercise might not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

When installing a fresh gem the gem will be installed in the GEM_HOME.  If that is not writable then it will try in the user's home `.gem` directory (on *NIX at least).

You could certainly script this. In a way Rail's `rake gems:build` is just this.  Just not on demand.

But, I would recommend against this.  You could run into build, versioning, dependency and network issues. And probably security issues as well.

PS: Francis Hwang did something related a while ago, although only as a require, not a require gems.

http://fhwang.net/2005/11/01/urirequire-I-got-yer-Web-2-0-right-here

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) and distribute the required gems with the application.

It is also quite simple to write a script to bootstrap the installation of gems if you didn't 
want to distribute them with your code (using the bundle install/check commands)